# deploy wcf service to IIS

Tags: wcf, wcf-hosting

I am a web newbie. I have absolutly 0 web (ASP.NET) experience. I am also a WCF newbie. So forgive me if I sound like one.
I created a WCF service that desktop applications use to comunicate. I have a client (the desktop app) project and a Service (the WCF service) project in one soluction. I added a Service reference to the client, and it works using Visual Studio's local ASP.NET Development server. I now want to move the service to reside on our IIS7 server. The server is on a different machine (in our intranet). I want the service (files and all) to sit on that machine and for that IIS server to 'host' it. What are the steps I have to do?
I have write access to subfolders on that machine, but I would have to go through the admin to do any changes to the 'iis configurations' so I would like to minimize that as much as possible. All that I know is that the current IIS root web.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".lnk" mimeType="Application/x-ms-shortcut" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".url" mimeType="Application/x-ms-shortcut" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".bat" mimeType="plain/text" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".rdp" mimeType="plain/text" />
        </staticContent>
        <handlers>
            <add name="svc-ISAPI-2.0" path="*.svc" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
            <add name="svc-Integrated" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

a complete step-by-step for idiots would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, figured it out. I just had the admin make the directory an "application" in iis.